# INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Boo tstrap requests on port 25249

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to restart my apachi nifi , but it is showing below message not getting   server up.

Below is the log from nifi-bootstrap.log

INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Boo
tstrap requests on port 25249
2018-06-13 11:09:20,346 INFO [main] o.a.n.b.NotificationServiceManager Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
2018-06-13 11:09:20,354 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
2018-06-13 11:09:20,355 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
2018-06-13 11:09:20,355 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
2018-06-13 11:09:20,390 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 25249, 
PID=24445
2018-06-13 11:09:53,964 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: null
2018-06-13 11:09:53,971 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Shutting down...
2018-06-13 11:09:54,738 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi

Can someone suggest where we can setup bootstrap port .

Regards,
SP

Comment: Can you please format your log? What is the OS? Can you check that the port is not already use? Perhaps by another NiFi instance?

Comment: This is the `nifi-bootstrap.log`; you should look in the `nifi-app.log` file to see the complete errors and why the NiFi application did not start up. The bootstrap port is determined dynamically at startup and is just used for IPC between the bootstrap process and the actual application. You do not configure it anywhere.

Comment: As suggested by @Andy, please share your `nifi-app.log`

Comment: I have checked nifi-app.log and found that error related to " java runtime evironment"  like there is insufficient memory for the java Runtime Environment to continue.